# Diff of two very large text files

Tags: java, diff

I have to text files:

```
file one: 400gb
file two: 411gb
```

These files are database dumps in rdf format.
The bigger file is the newer and it has new 
data. 11gb of the data are new.

I want to do a file diff to get this new 11gb
of data to import the new data into my database
without touching the old.

How can i do it efficiently using java?

Comment: Do you need to do it in Java? Have you tried `diff --speed-large-files` ?

Comment: its the database dump from google freebase. and yes: it ahs to be java ^^

Comment: @fge has written a library called [largetext](https://github.com/fge/largetext), that I don't think can directly help, but may be of interest. It's for handling large files on the order of around 4GB.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can work with files of that size, but there is at least one [java xdelta](http://javaxdelta.sourceforge.net/) implementation.